# Modify slice of a dataframe inplace in a function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a function that performs HTTP requests on some columns of a pd.DataFrame then stores the value of the response to another column. So for each row.
So here is a MWE:

```py
import pandas as pd
def myFunc(df:pd.DataFrame, groupName: str) -> None:
    print(df)
    # initialising the column.
    df.loc[:,f"{groupName} removal status"] = ''
    # starting working on each line
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        row[f"{groupName} removal status"] = 'ok'
        print(row[f"{groupName} removal status"]) # prints 'ok' for each line
```

Thing is I want to filter out the DataFrame I pass to this function, on some properties (in my case it is a column wether or not we want to remove a user from a group). So this is how I call the function:

```py
myFunc(users_toDeactivate.loc[users_toDeactivate['remove user from group'] == True,:], groupName = 'whatever groupname')
```

I am expecting the original dataframe `users_toDeactivate` to have a new column "whatever groupname removal status" in that case, partially filled with "ok" values for the slice I passed to the function.

Instead the following warning shows up and the df is not modified "SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

Of course I need to perform the action on various groups, hence the function, and I want to keep the original dataframe and partially fill it for each so that I can export it all at once in a csv acting as a log file and saving the status of each action.

Before jumping into deep mofications of my code, I would rather ask if it is possible to do it the way I intend it to be.

Comment: iterrows to conditionally asign a value to some cells? This can probably be vectorized. Care to craft a representative [mre] with input df and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Up to my knowledge, Yes.

But first note that `SettingWithCopyWarning`, typically because you try to modify a DataFrame that is a slice of another DataFrame. THis is not explicitly allowed in Pandas.

I suggest using `.loc` accessor with a condition inside your function to modify only the relevant rows of the DataFrame.

Try this attempt, it worked for my up to my understanding for the question

```
import pandas as pd

def myFunc(df: pd.DataFrame, groupName: str, condition) -> None:
    # create the non-existing column first
    if f"{groupName} removal status" not in df.columns:
        df[f"{groupName} removal status"] = ''

    # Search the DF for those following your predefined condition
    df.loc[condition, f"{groupName} removal status"] = 'ok'

# main body below
users_toDeactivate = pd.DataFrame({
    'user': ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4'],
    'remove user from group': [True, False, True, False]
})

myFunc(users_toDeactivate, groupName='whatever groupname', condition=(users_toDeactivate['remove user from group'] == True))

print(users_toDeactivate)
```

BR